# Listview OnItemclicklistener not responding in Switch case Statement

Tags: android, listview

I am working on an application and in `OnItemclick` method i used Switch Statement for `listview` and when i am tapping on position 0 , it shows the position 0 item. and when i am tapping on position 1 on the same time it doesn't respond . 
Here is the code:

```
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,

                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, sims));

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Selectitem(position);

                 switch (position) {
                 case 0:
                 mapBeginConfigcities();
                 // mapBeginConfig();
                 loadUI();
                 mapEndConfig();
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "0"+position,
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 break;

                 case 1:
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "1" + position,
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 mapBeginRoadsfill();
                 loadUI();
                 mapEndConfig();
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "1" + position,
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 break;

                 case 2:
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "2" + position,
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 break;
                 case 3:
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "3" + position,
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 break;

                 default:

                 break;
                 }

            }

            public void Selectitem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                setTitle(sims[position]);

            }

            public void setTitle(String title) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Is it going inside the Case 1: block ?

Comment: can we see the method mapBeginRoadsfill? Because it is the only method which is not in the case 0 block

Comment: yes its going... but if i select case 1 first . i can't get any response on Case 2 or others . and vice versa.

Comment: In every case there is another method .

Comment: try clicking item  2-3-1... 2 & 3 case doesnt have any method call , if it works fine it mean that `loadUI();` or `mapEndConfig();` might be doing something wrong here

Comment: Hitesh your problem is  list.setItemChecked(position, true);..You are selecting item checked after you select a position.That's why its not reseting again.

Comment: @funlove - i removed the whole method which contains list.setitemchecked . still the same problem

Comment: There must be some flaw in your custom method..Do one thing swap your case 1 with case 0.and check the problem appears for Case 0 or not

Comment: Okay let me just check.